# Rails Simple_Form Association Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

New to RoR. I am making a simple blog to post music entries. I have two models Tune and Artist where a tune belongs_to an artist. I am using simple_form to render my form. The problem I am running into is that the simple_form is pulling up the correct associations but when I click submit it is not saving the association correctly and the validation isn't passing. Code is below:

Classes

```
class Tune < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  validates :artist, presence: true
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tunes
end
```

Database schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131027190309) do

  create_table "artists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "real_name"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "artist_soundcloud_link"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "tunes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "soundcloud_link"
    t.string   "download_link"
    t.string   "download_label"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "style"
    t.boolean  "mix"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "artist_id"
  end

  add_index "tunes", ["artist_id"], name: "index_tunes_on_artist_id"

end
```

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for @tune, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :soundcloud_link %>
  <%= f.input :download_label %>
  <%= f.input :download_link %>
  <%= f.input :mix %>
  <%= f.association :artist%>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following to your Tune model

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :tunes
```

and then add strong params to your controller, e.g.

```
params.require(:artist).permit( :id, :name, ... , tune_attributes: [:id, :name, :real_name, ...] )
```

NOTE: I am assuming your are using rails 4

Comment: Still running into the same issue. I think you are right that it is has to do with nested attributes but in this case artist is the parent class and tune is the child class (has column artist_id). When I read through the documentation the accepts_nested_attributes_for is usually assigned on the parent class, not the child class.

Comment: why you are doing  validates :artist, presence: true ?. Artist should be validated in artist model. Remove it and try. Can you past your console output for the error ?